# Remove extra padding on start of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

The start text of textinput layout is getting cut

Is it possible to remove the padding inside the textinput layout?

TextInput style

```
   <style name="Widget.TextInputLayoutx" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">?spacerSmall</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundMode">outline</item>
    </style>
```

Custom View for textinput layout

```
   <com.custom.android.design.amount.input.InputAmountView
        android:id="@+id/amountInputView"
        style="@style/Widget.TextInputLayoutx"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:paddingVertical="0dp"
        app:errorIconDrawable="@null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvCurrency"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amountTitle" />
```

[image: The start text of textinput layout is getting cut]

Answer (score 0):

```
You can just set the start and end padding on the inner EditText to 0dp.

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```